# Develop C in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm looking to develop C, not C++ in Code::Blocks. I've scoured the web to see if I can find out any specific information about how to do so in the IDE, but no luck.

Can I just use the Console Application template and code/compile as normal, using C syntax? Anyone with any idea of how this would work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CodeBlocks compiles .c files with the C compiler by default.

Comment: I see it actually gives you an explicit choice when you choose Console Application in the wizard that comes up. Would g++ compile C or would I need to download another compiler?

Comment: GCC includes gcc for C and g++ for C++.

Comment: @chris Formulate a basic, comprehensive answer and you got the check.

Comment: To avoid linking to libstdc++ when building C projects (with GCC), you can make a copy of the "GNU GCC Compiler" settings, and under "Toolchain executables" change the "Linker for dynamic libs" option to gcc instead of g++.  Then use the modified copy as the compiler when working with C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click <kbd>Console Application</kbd> this box should come up asking you to choose your language:

[image]

And as stated in the comments, when you are compiling C code, GCC uses the gcc compiler, and with C++, the g++ compiler.

Comment: And for compiling single files without a project, it's just dependent on the file extension.